# Como mudar o valor de uma variável dentro de uma função em javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou com um problema e não sei bem como resolver, sou novo em javascript e não to conseguindo alterar um valor de uma variável externa dentro de uma função interna do .then:

```
var DadosCadastrados = function(){
    var dados = 1;
    User.findAll().then(cads => {
        dados = 2;
    }).catch(erro =>{
        dados = 3
    })
    console.log(dados)
    return dados
}
```

dados continua sendo printado como 1 e não como 2. como eu faço pra alterar o valor dele? (obs: a função then está sendo chamada e eu coloquei um console.log(dados) dentro de then e ele retorna 2, mas volta a ser 1 novamente)

Comment: A variável dados = 1, está no escopo globa e as outras estão dentro de uma Arow Function, as variáveis dentro de uma função não ficam visíveis fora da função. Portanto, o console.log vai retornar a variável de fora da função.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repara que a tua função tem partes assíncronas e por isso não podes ter um `return` de um valor síncrono.

O retorno que esperas dessa função tem de ser consumido com um `.then(` assincronamente. Consequentemente se queres ter um retorno do `then` interno e do `catch` interno tens de retornar algo dentro desse `then` e `catch` e retornar também a Promise que é esse `User.findAll()`.

Fiz um exemplo onde mudo a ideia de `User.findAll()` por uma Promise que resolve ou falha para mostrar as duas linhas de lógica em ação:

```js
const DadosCadastrados = function(resolution) {
  return Promise[resolution]().then(cads => {
    return 'passou';
  }).catch(erro => {
    return 'falhou';
  });
}

DadosCadastrados('resolve').then(res => console.log(res)); // passou
DadosCadastrados('reject').then(res => console.log(res)); // falhou
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá, acredito que você deseja retornar resultado do find, o problema é que o find é um método assíncrono de forma que a chamada do then pode ser executada depois da função retorna, poderia dar 2 sugestões:

1. Verificar a possibilidade da utilização de async await
2. utilizar uma promise para retornar o resultado da função

Ex.:

```html
var DadosCadastrados = function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      User.findAll().then(cads => {
          resolve(2);
      }).catch(erro =>{
          resolve(3)
      })
    })
}

DadosCadastrados().then(v => {
  console.log(v);
})
```